# How To Use Pry When Using SSH

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pry

I believe I'm in production the server and connecting to it via ssh on my terminal. I'm able to hit pry, but I can't get it show to in terminal because everything is ran as a background process.

Help?

Comment: Why would everything be run as a background process? What kind of shell are you using? Normal `ssh` and `bash` should not do this.

Comment: it's been daemonized so that the server can keep running. I'm not sure if I'm explaining it correctly. But we have a remote machine hosted. It runs the app and has a server running. I can ssh in to access the code, etc.

Comment: That sounds like a very strange way to deploy your application. Why not use something like [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com) to host your Rails application? That's considerably more reliable than a background process.

Comment: Actually, it might be using Passenger. That's what the readme says. Firehost using Passenger and Apache.

Comment: That's good then. As to why `pry` isn't working, it should be. Do other things like `vi` or `nano` work properly? If not, your shell is severely messed up.

Comment: Yes nano works. I can edit files. I can hit the binding.remote_pry, but I can't debug it.

Comment: Give `irb` a shot, that's the standard one, or `rails console` for your application.

Comment: rails console and irb works, but how do I hit the pry when I refresh the web page?

Comment: `pry` is totally independent of your Rails application, normally it just starts up a bare Ruby environment. There is no default way to debug your application if that's what you're asking. You need to add-on that functionality.

Comment: So how would you suggest I debug the app when I refresh the web page. Is it possible via ssh?

Comment: You don't. If you've got a problem on your production server the best plan is to reproduce it on your local development machine and watch `log/development.log` very closely. If you've got a problem in some part of your code, narrow it down, add `Rails.logger.debug` calls if necessary, and even better, add in unit tests to verify functionality.

Comment: I see. Thanks @tadman. I'll try to get it back on my dev machine.